# Installing Chromium on Raspberry Pi running Arch linux with pacman

Tags: linux, chromium, archlinux, pacman-package-manager

I have a Raspberry Pi running: Linux 3.10.35-1-ARCH

How do I install the chromium web browser?  I have tried the following:

> pacman -Syyu

Followed by

> pacman -S chromium
>
> error: target not found: chromium

When I've downloaded the 'google-chrome-dev' from AUR it says:

> ==> ERROR: google-chrome-dev is not available for the 'armv6h' architecture.
>       Note that many packages may need a line added to their PKGBUILD
>       such as arch=('armv6h').

I'm beginning to think that chromium doesn't exist on Arch linux.  Any thought on how to install it?

Comment: This is not a software development question, it would be a better fit on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: sorry, it's my first time posting.  I'll try and post it on raspberry.stackexchange.com... How would I do this?

Comment: Moonman seems to have got it to work and [has done a great job sharing his process](http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=5645). Also, the [PKGBUILDs repo](https://github.com/archlinuxarm/PKGBUILDs/) also has a customized build file in the extra/chromium directory which is supposed to work for arm6. Also, see [the related question raspberry pi stack exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15882/unable-to-compile-chromium)

Answer (score 1):

try `sudo pacman -S chromium-browser` or `sudo pacman -S extra/chromium`

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The ARM version of ArchLinux only has packages to armv7.

You can try to compile it using `makepkg` or `packer`, but I wouldn't be surprised if this would take hours/days...

If you want to try, download [this](https://github.com/archlinuxarm/PKGBUILDs/blob/master/extra/chromium/PKGBUILD) file to some directory and run in the same path

```
$ makepkg
```